# Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga compatible wacom-pen

Tags: wacom

I bought [Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga](http://www.pcconnection.com/product/lenovo-thinkpad-s1-yoga-core-i5-4300u-1.9ghz-8gb-256gb-ssd-ac-bt-wc-pen-8c-12.5-fhd-ag-w8.1p64/20c0004sus/16812687) that has [wacom pen](http://forum.tabletpcreview.com/threads/wacom-emr-vs-n-trig-vs-wacom-aes.65666/), but it doesn't have eraser.

I bought a [Wacom Pen CTH470](https://www.tokopedia.com/snapshot.pl?dtl_id=39713932&order_id=25652537), but it doesn't work on the Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga, either it's fake, broken, or the pen tip is fake (it looks like plastic, different from the built-in pen from Lenovo), or it's not compatible with Lenovo's.

The question is,

1. how to make sure what's wrong with the pen I bought?
2. what's other pen model that can work with my thinkpad, that have 2 buttons and eraser?

Comment: The pen tip *should* look plastic unless you specifically bought the optional felt nib or the inking pen. And the eraser isn't necessarily a pen feature; not all tablets/digitizers support the eraser feature.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but since it got no answer I thought I should pitch in.

I have a Wacom Intuos 5 (Pro) and 3 pens. I also got a Lenovo Yoga for work, and its pen is made by Wacom. The first thing I tried was to use one of my Wacom pens with the Yoga -- It did not work.

I also got a Bamboo Touch tablet that comes with the pen you mentioned as a gift from Wacom (long story -- they messed up one of my orders and sent me this gift to make it up). That pen does not work with my Intuos, and my Intuos Pens do not work with the Bamboo tablet either.

So unfortunately, the pens are not interchangeable across devices just because they're all Wacom. I would love to use a Art pen with the Yoga -- but that isn't going to happen :-(

Also I am not sure about your Thinkpad Yoga, but for mine the pen slides into the laptop ([figure](http://www.laptopmag.com/images/uploads/4696/g/x1-yoga-stylus.jpg)), where it charges. It is a battery-enabled pen, while the pens for the Intuos an Bamboo work without any battery. Anyway that should only be an additional indicator that these pens are not interchangeable.

Perhaps Lenovo has a special pen for that purpose? I would go to shop.lenovo.com and see if there are any pens that are compatible with your Yoga. Once you find one, you might be able to find it being sold elsewhere for a cheaper price?